# Setting float value to a bool pandas column without conversion to float

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test':[False,True,True]})
df2.loc[0,'Test']=np.nan
```

The above result df converting the 'test' column to floats, where the True's get converting into 1.0. Is it possible to set this value, keeping the dtype of the column to obj so I can mix float and bool's, i.e.

```
    test
0   NaN
1   True
2   True
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `dtype=object`

Yes.  You need to tell Pandas that the column is of `dtype` object

```
pd.DataFrame({'test':[False,True,True]}, dtype=object)
```

If altering an existing dataframe

```
df2['test'] = df2['test'].astype(object)
```

Comment: If this column is already present in a dataframe, how do I convert it to object? Eg. assume starting from the line ```df2.loc[0,'test']=np.nan```

Comment: `df['test']  = df2['test'].astype('object')` before assing values.

Comment: `dtype='category'` also seems to work. Might be a bit nicer on the memory usage with just T/F/NaN

Comment: I wonder.  It would still have to store an array of `0/1/2`s versus an array of `True/False/NaN`